# Differential and Common currents in EMI Design

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I need some clarifications about an application note from ON Semiconductor I have downloaded form the following site:

http://www.icbase.com/pdf/add/on/AN-106-00003en.pdf

The discription of the differential and common mode given in the application when referred to figure 1b, confused me!

[image]

[image]

What confused me is the statement encircled (Maybe my English is not good enough)
If we look to the image both DM source and CM1 are sourcing up and yet it has been said that DM is out of phase in each branch and CM is in phase both to the DC rail and ground.

1. What is it meant by these two statements?
2. Can someone redraw the direction of both currents through the whole circuit ?

Comment: It may be easier to think of DM and CM noise this way: DM noise flows through your circuit in the "intended" path. It goes through the input and back out the return path. CM noise on the other hand flows through both your input and return (in the same direction) and returns through an Earth connection whether intentional or parasitic.

Comment: @Stiddily I posted this application note because it is useful for simulation, this is why I'm trying to understand it! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below picture should shed more light on the way these currents circulate in the circuit:

[image]

The differential-mode currents can be quite easily predicted with a simulator considering the below scheme while common-mode types are more difficult to predict/model as they involve PCB layout, stray capacitance with heatsinks (if any) or inter-winding capacitance for instance:

[image]

You will need dedicated receiver and line impedance stabilization network or LISN to assess the level of noise. Please note it is best to combine signals coming from the LISN line and neutral outputs to isolate differential- and common-mode contributors.

[image]

The LISN is there to fix the grid output impedance to 50 ohms from 150 kHz to 30 MHz. That way, measurements performed in France or in the US are done on the same grid output impedance.

*Disclaimer*: I plead guilty for writing the application note you referred to. I was wearing short pants at that time : )